# Isomorphisms of elliptic curves defined over different finite fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $K$ be a non-trivial extension of a finite field (to fix ideas, assume $K = \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ for a prime $p$), and $E/K$ an elliptic curve defined over $K$.

Is it possible to find a different finite field $K'$, another elliptic curve $E'/K'$ and a group isomorphism (e.g. preserving addition of points) $\phi: E/K \to E'/K'$? I am particularly interested in the case where $K'$ has a lower extension degree than $K$ (think $K' = \mathbb{F}_q$ where $q$ is prime).

My first intuition says no, because the algebraic structure of a curve changes too much when changing the finite field, but then for $K = K'$, isogenies exist, so perhaps there is some specific relation between the fields and equations that could make this work. Some kind of *"cross-field" isogeny*. The main application is cryptography, so I would actually be satisfied if there is such isomorphism between the largest subgroups of each curve (motivation is to implement addition in $E/\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ with the help of addition in $E'/\mathbb{F}_p$).

Comment: What do you mean by $\phi$ being an isomorphism of elliptic curves over *different* ground fields? Are you base changing them both to a common extension field? If so, as written can't you take $E'$ to be any elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_q$ and $E$ to be its base change to $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$?

Comment: You may delete the other copy. Since we don't want a cross-site question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: Welcome to MSE! :)
Could you expand on what kind of morphism $\phi$ you're looking for? As $E$ and $E'$ are varieties over different fields, it's unclear to me what you mean by $E\mid_K$ and $E'\mid_{K'}$ to be isomorphic. If you want $E$ and $E'$ to be isomorphic as varieties (i.e. as schemes over $\text{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$) then $E$ is isomorphic to itself when thought of as a variety of $\text{Spec} \mathbb{F}_p$ where $\mathbb{F}_p \subseteq K$.

Comment: In this case (elliptic curves), there is a group structure (addition of points) so I meant a group isomorphism. I edited. Let me know if there are other concerns.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding something here. The group scheme structure requires in a sort of essential way the base scheme to be fixed. The issue is that if $G$ is an $S$-group scheme, then certainly by composing the structure map $G\to S$ with any map $S\to T$ (e.g. the unique map $S\to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$) you can think of $G$ as a $T$-scheme as well. But, this composition $G\to S\to T$ has zero reasons to inherit the structure of a group $T$-scheme. Thus, there's not a lot of sense in asking whether or not $E/K$ and $E'/K'$ are isomorphic -- while you could compare

Comment: $E$ and $E'$ as schemes (i.e. as $\mathbb{Z}$-schemes after composing with the maps $\mathrm{Spec}(K)\to\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ and $\mathrm{Spec}(K')\to\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$) it doesn't make sense to compare them with their group structures intact.

Comment: I am not sure I follow this argument. Any elliptic curve over a finite field has a certain group structure via addition of points, and it turns out it is either cyclic or product of two cyclic groups. Are you implying that there is no possible combination of finite fields and curve equations such that they are homomorphic as groups (e.g. there exists a map that preserves addition)? What about isomorphic (large) subgroups?

Comment: (Also, please bear with me as I'm certainly missing tools, could you point a reference to understand how curves and the spectrum of $\mathbb Z$ relate? Is there some kind of a canonical map? You mention Spec($K$) but since $K$ is a finite field, isn't the spectrum trivial?)

Comment: The groups $E(K)$ and $E'(K')$ can certainly be isomorphic (happens trivially if both share the same prime as their order). But describing such an isomorphism in terms of well-defined rational functions seems out of reach. Heck, how would you even describe a function from $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ to $\Bbb{F}_q$? The only way I could think of producing such a function $E(K)\to E'(K')$ would be to map a generator of one to the generator of another. But that defeats the whole purpose because then you need to solve the DLP to even define the function.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this.
(First, a nitpick, elliptic curves defined over quadratic extensions cannot have a prime order (Lagrange for a quick argument, and see for instance e.g. Silverman AOE, exercise 5.13 for a closed form). So for the sake of the argument, let's assume that we are speaking about two (large) subgroups of $E(K)$ and $E'(K')$ with same prime order.)
Now if they have the same prime order, and we have map sending the gen $G_1\in E(K)$ to the gen $G_2 \in E'(K')$ we want it to commute with scalar multiplication, and that is the hard pard is your claim. Is this correct?